# Optimising LINQ To Entities Without Returning Large Anonymous Type Set

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, query-optimization

I'm currently trying to optimise some of my LINQ to Entity queries (EF 6.1.1) so that the generated SQL is more efficient. I've managed to refactor my statements so that the SQL is pretty much how I would write it, however I am running into issue with the return objects from the query.

One relatively simple example would be where I originally I had lambda syntax with something like this:

```cs
var originalQuery = context.WorkstationConfigurations
                           .Include(config => config.WorkstationOptions)
                           .Include(config => config.WorkstationOptions.Select(option => option.ImageWorkstationOption))
                           .Include(config => config.WorkstationOptions.Select(option => option.ImageWorkstationOption).Select(iwo => iwo.Image))
                           .Include(config => config.WorkstationPowerBarTileAssignments);
List<WorkstationConfiguration> originalResult = originalQuery.ToList();
```

This correctly returned a list of 3 WorkstationConfiguration entites, with the object graph all correctly hooked up, but it produced pretty horrific SQL with multiple selects, unions, order by's, etc:

```
SELECT 
[UnionAll1].[RowVersion] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll1].[WorkstationConfigurationID] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll1].[Name] AS [C3], 
...
...
FROM  (SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ([Join2].[Name1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    [Extent1].[WorkstationConfigurationID] AS [WorkstationConfigurationID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[ConfigurationType] AS [ConfigurationType], 
    [Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion1], 
    [Join2].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
    ...
    ...
    FROM  [dbo].[WorkstationConfiguration] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], [Extent2].[LineNumber] AS [LineNumber1], [Extent2].[WorkstationConfigurationID] AS [WorkstationConfigurationID1], [Extent2].[TypeCode] AS [TypeCode], [Extent2].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion1], [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name2], [Extent3].[LineNumber] AS [LineNumber2], [Extent3].[WorkstationConfigurationID] AS [WorkstationConfigurationID2], [Extent3].[ImageID] AS [ImageID1], [Extent3].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion2], [Extent4].[ImageID] AS [ImageID2], [Extent4].[ImageData] AS [ImageData], [Extent4].[SizeInBytes] AS [SizeInBytes], [Extent4].[WidthInPixels] AS [WidthInPixels], [Extent4].[HeightInPixels] AS [HeightInPixels], [Extent4].[ImageHash] AS [ImageHash], [Extent4].[Description] AS [Description], [Extent4].[ImageTypeID] AS [ImageTypeID], [Extent4].[ContentType] AS [ContentType], [Extent4].[ThumbnailImageData] AS [ThumbnailImageData], [Extent4].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion3]
        FROM   [dbo].[WorkstationOption] AS [Extent2]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ImageWorkstationOption] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent2].[WorkstationConfigurationID] = [Extent3].[WorkstationConfigurationID]) AND ([Extent2].[LineNumber] = [Extent3].[LineNumber]) AND ([Extent2].[Name] = [Extent3].[Name])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Image] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ImageID] = [Extent4].[ImageID] ) AS [Join2] ON [Extent1].[WorkstationConfigurationID] = [Join2].[WorkstationConfigurationID1]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    2 AS [C1], 
    [Extent5].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    [Extent5].[WorkstationConfigurationID] AS [WorkstationConfigurationID], 
    [Extent5].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent5].[ConfigurationType] AS [ConfigurationType], 
    [Extent5].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion1], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
    ...
    ...
    FROM  [dbo].[WorkstationConfiguration] AS [Extent5]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[WorkstationPowerBarTileAssignment] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[WorkstationConfigurationID] = [Extent6].[WorkstationConfigurationID]) AS [UnionAll1]
ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[WorkstationConfigurationID] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC
```

So after a bit of googling I found that query syntax is better for multiple joins/complex queries, so I refactored to this:

```cs
var optimisedQuery = from workstationConfiguration in context.WorkstationConfigurations
                     from workstationOption in workstationConfiguration.WorkstationOptions
                     from tileAssignment in workstationConfiguration.WorkstationPowerBarTileAssignments.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                            {
                              a = workstationConfiguration,
                              b = workstationOption,
                              c = workstationOption.ImageWorkstationOption,
                              d = workstationOption.ImageWorkstationOption.Image,
                              e = tileAssignment
                            };
var optimisedResult = optimisedQuery.ToList();
```

This produced pretty much perfect SQL (single select, correct joins) like I would have written if I had hand rolled it:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
[Extent1].[WorkstationConfigurationID] AS [WorkstationConfigurationID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[ConfigurationType] AS [ConfigurationType], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
...
...
FROM [dbo].[WorkstationConfiguration] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[WorkstationOption] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[WorkstationConfigurationID] = [Extent2].[WorkstationConfigurationID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WorkstationPowerBarTileAssignment] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[WorkstationConfigurationID] = [Extent3].[WorkstationConfigurationID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ImageWorkstationOption] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent2].[Name] = [Extent4].[Name]) AND ([Extent2].[LineNumber] = [Extent4].[LineNumber]) AND ([Extent2].[WorkstationConfigurationID] = [Extent4].[WorkstationConfigurationID])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Image] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[ImageID] = [Extent5].[ImageID]
```

Entity framework takes care of populating the object graph correctly (all objects and nav properties hooked up correctly), but I end up with one anonymous type entry for every row returned from the database (316), rather than a set of 3 distinct WorkstationConfiguration objects. So if I manually pull out the unique WorkstationConfiguration objects ('a') from the result set then I have the same end result, but with optimised SQL.

Is there a way I can get the optimised SQL, with the child entities all populated/object graph all automatically hooked up, without getting the superfluous set of anonymous types (i.e. get a List<WorkstationConfiguration> directly returned from my optimised LINQ statement)?